# Reverse a flag after post is edited

Tags: feature-request, flags

I often find that I see something and I flag it up, but then the post is edited and I want to undo my flag.

So I think that a feature which would allow for you, at least within the first 5-10 minutes of taking the action, to reverse it.

Comment: If you often find yourself choosing the "wrong" action when doing reviews, perhaps you should simply slow down.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce: I don't find it that often, it mostly occurs when I have been looking at something a long time and then I decide that I am going to flag it up, but am so used to the other review queue where you just click the "Recommend Deletion" button, that I just automatically click where that button would be, but the of course as I am in the wrong review queue, I mark it as "No action needed". It has only happened to me twice, but a way of reversing very recent reviews would still be useful.

Comment: "It has only happened to me twice" is hardly worth a feature request surely? Besides, only making two mistake in this scenario has hardly given you time to *remember* to not do it again/be more careful.

Comment: @James: But what have you got against a feature which would allow people to reverse their actions on items? I think that a lot of people would find it rather useful, and unless there is a reason not to implement it, I do not see why implementing it would be a problem. Even if most people would not need to use it, a 'back' button is always important.

Comment: @Toroidal Features all have costs.  If you can't provide compelling reasons for why the feature would outweigh those costs, then it's not worth developing.  On top of everything else, there is the opportunity cost; the feature needs to be better than the net benefits of every single other feature SE could have spent its time on instead of building this.

Comment: Why have you changed your entire proposal to something completely different? From "undo on review queue actions" to "undo flags"? Mine and Servy's answers are now in part obsolete, and this has been closed as a dupe. Was this change because people disagreed with you? Because you had clearly described an issue with "*review queue*" because you've made some mistakes in reviewing, not *flags*.

Comment: @James: Somebody else asked me to change it to what it currently is. You can role it back though if you like.

Comment: If I roll it back, then we'll have to un dupe it as it will no longer be a dupe. Just take some time and consider outcomes before actions - in reviewing, and changing feature requests after two people have answered. No matter. This is closed, let's move on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @James: But what have you got against a feature which would allow
>   people to reverse their actions on items?

People get complacent when they have an undo button. They would make *more* mistakes because of a safety net, and considering that the tiny amount of issues which will be currently happening, I just don't see a requirement.

> I think that a lot of people would find it rather useful

But a lot of people *shouldn't* find it useful. I'm ok with a few mistakes here and there by a few users, but if a problem exists in such a scale whereby an undo button on reviews would be "useful", then we have a bigger problem to resolve (users not able to review accurately).

This is not a word processor, or a blog post, where undo, edit, rollback, etc, are welcomed. This is a "control panel" and the buttons have real implications to the content on the site, and buttons you and I press even potential ramifications towards other users (if they have too many black marks etc).

This requires some care, consideration, and being careful with said buttons, not a hammy "undo" because we cannot be sensible adults and use it with professionalism.

> Even if most people would not need to use it

Then it is not worth dev time planning, discussing, implementing, managing, maintaining, updating, etc.

> a 'back' button is always important

I do not have one, and manage just fine. I don't think I've actually ever pressed the wrong button.
Maybe I will one day, maybe twice next week, that hardly warrants a whole new feature on the site.

Answer (score 6):

There's a reason that it takes as many votes as it does to act on a post in review queues.  Part of it is so that (rare) mistakes like this don't cause problems ([if this is happening a lot; there's a bigger problem you need to solve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252974/reverse-a-review/252975#comment826155_252974)); if a post really needs actions, future reviewers will be able to handle it.